# Error at second time button click while performing Update on DataGridView multiple selected rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, debugging, unhandled-exception

When I click the button **"Pay Remaining Fee"**, it works perfectly on first click. But when I click the button **"Pay Remaining Fee"** a 2nd time I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

---

Code of Button Click is given below:

```
private void btnPayRemainingFee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvRemaining.SelectedRows != null && dgvRemaining.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int remainFee = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvRemaining.SelectedRows.Count; ++i)
            {
                int idFee = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRemaining.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                string monthFee = Convert.ToString(dgvRemaining.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                int paidFee= Convert.ToInt32(dgvRemaining.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                remainFee = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRemaining.SelectedRows[i].Cells[3].Value);

                //updating feePayment table of specific student
                var payFee = feeDb.tblFeePayment.Where(x => x.pay_std_id == studentId && x.pay_id == idFee ).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();

                payFee.pay_date = System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
                int feeRemain = Convert.ToInt32(payFee.pay_feeRemained);
                if(remainFee==feeRemain)
                {
                    payFee.pay_feeRemained = "0";
                    payFee.pay_amount = Convert.ToString(paidFee + remainFee);
                }
                else
                {

                }
                feeDb.SaveChanges();
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please! Select Record/s to pay fee!..");
        }
        //dgvRemaining populate
        var res2 = from r in feeDb.tblFeePayment
                   where r.pay_std_id == studentId && r.pay_feeRemained != null && r.pay_feeRemained != "0"
                   select new { Remaining_Month = r.pay_ofWhichMonth, Paid_Amount = r.pay_amount, Remaining_Amount = r.pay_feeRemained };
        dgvRemaining.DataSource = res2.ToList();
        dgvRemaining.Refresh();
        dgvRemaining.Focus();
    }
```

Error line is:

`int idFee = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRemaining.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value);`

---

***ScreenShots of error are given here!***

- [Interface Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnuGX.png)
- [Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foLeW.png)

Comment: Isn't the dgvRemaining.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value is "Month" column. The exception in the screenshot says unable to convert DateTime!

Comment: No, this is not the issue, i have tried it..

Comment: @MoonaKanwal : Looking at your interface, the first column seems to be for Month Name. But at the line(the one you get the error at), you are trying to convert it to Int32. Practically, a string cannot be converted to int. So, maybe this is the error.

Comment: @D J you are right, but the same code works perfectly when I press the Payment button 1st time. but when I click the button 2nd time I get this error..